# Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below function to get values from database.

The problem is when i select column of type int.

i get this error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`

in this line `result.Add(dr.GetString(0));`

**Code**

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string value, string filterBy)
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        con.Open();
        string command = string.Format("select {0} from Users where {0} LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", filterBy);
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", value);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Users table structure**

```
UserID   type int
UserName type nvarchar(50)
Password type nvarchar(50)
```

Comment: Could you show us your table structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `result.Add(dr.GetValue(0).ToString());`

To avoid the return of GetValue() being null, do this -

```
result.Add((sqlreader.IsDBNull(0) ? "" : dr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the answer is what it is? It's not very helpful to anyone to actually understand the problem if you don't explain it and how to solve and why it is.

Comment: great. please select as answer if it resolved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Also, just in case it may be null value, I'll add constraint to check for null condition. I'll add it to my answer for you.

Answer (score 8):

> when i select column of type int

According to the code, you're trying to select a column of type `string`:

```
dr.GetString(0)
```

If the column is an `int`, then get an `int`:

```
dr.GetInt32(0)
```

Which you can then convert to a `string` for your list:

```
result.Add(dr.GetInt32(0).ToString());
```

---

Specifically regarding the error, note the text in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring.aspx):

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.

Comment: This should be marked as answer as it explains the issue well, and also explains resolving it

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same type of error: **'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'**

Here if you want to bind string value means

```
dr.GetString(1)
```

Either if you want to print int value means

```
dr.GetInt32(0)
```

and i got one more error :**Specified cast is not valid.**

if you want string means u need to put

```
dr.GetString(1)
```

initially i did `dr.GetString(0)` which shows Specified cast is not valid.
same thing if you need int value means you need to put `dr.GetInt32(0)` not `dr.GetInt32(1)`